# Does Jenkins blue ocean cache pipelines scripts somewhere?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

When i run a build I'm getting an older version of the pipeline in the UI instead of the updated one. If i go to the legacy view of jenkins i see the updated version as expected. Some suggestionsabout this problem?

Comment: Probably there is a cache somewhere. I've noticed that if you run the build and it passes then the next run will have the correct data in the UI. It seems that it caches ui data of the last successufl build sowewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an instance of [a known bug](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-56171) in the Blue Ocean view, which has been open since 2019.

Please feel free to vote on it, though please also note that [the Blue Ocean view is now deprecated](https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users/c/xngZrSsXIjc/m/btasuPpYCgAJ) in favor of the [pipeline-graph-view](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-graph-view/) plugin (still in alpha as of this writing, but actively developed), though it's possible that the same issue exists in the new plugin.